# Accessing JSTL values of JSP from spring controller

Tags: spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, servlets

Below is my body in a jsp file. In my spring application, I wanna forward all the div values to my controller. I tried to access the data of one div (with name='atcId') which I am unable to do.

```
<body>
    <br>
    <div class="head" style="text-align:center; width:80px; float:left">
        Route 
    </div>
    <div class="head" style="text-align:center; width:300px; float:left">
        Date
    </div>
    <div class="head" style="text-align:center; width:140px; float:left">
        Time
    </div>
    <div class="head" style="text-align:right; width:100px; float:left">
        Capacity
    </div>
    <div class="head" style="text-align:center; width:100px; float:left">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="head" id="empty" style="text-align:center; width:80px; float:left">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="head" style="text-align:center; width:150px; float:left">
        From
    </div>
    <div class="head" style="text-align:center; width:150px; float:left">
        To
    </div>
    <div class="head" style="text-align:center; width:70px; float:left">
        From
    </div>
    <div class="head" style="text-align:center; width:70px; float:left">
        To
    </div>
    <div class="head" style="text-align:right; width:100px; float:left">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="head" style="text-align:center; width:100px; float:left">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <form action='atc/edit.htm' method="post">
        <c:forEach items="${atcMap}" var="atc" varStatus="status">
            <div style='float:left'>
                <div class="data" name="atcId" style="text-align:center; width:80px; float:left">
                    <c:out value="${atc.key.elements.name}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="data" style="text-align:center; width:150px; float:left">
                    <c:out value="${atc.key.id.fromDate}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="data" style="text-align:center; width:150px; float:left">
                    <c:out value="${atc.key.toDate}"/>
                </div>
                <div style='float:left'>
                    <c:forEach items="${atc.value}" var="atcSchedule" varStatus="status">
                        <div class="data" id="atcId" style="text-align:center; width:70px; float:left">
                            <c:out value="${atcSchedule.id.fromBlock}"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="data" style="text-align:center; width:70px; float:left">
                            <c:out value="${atcSchedule.toBlock}"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="data" style="text-align:right; width:100px; float:left">
                            <c:out value="${atcSchedule.capacity}"/>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </c:forEach>
                </div>
                &nbsp;
                &nbsp;
                &nbsp;
                <input type="image" width="25" height="25" name="action" id="image" value="modify" src="<c:url value="/resources/images/modify.png"/>" alt="Modify">
                &nbsp;
                &nbsp;
                <input type="image" width="25" height="25" name="action" id="image" value="delete" src="<c:url value="/resources/images/delete.png"/>" alt="Delete">
            </div>
            <div style='clear:both'>
            </div>
            <hr id="rowbreak" style="text-align: center">
        </c:forEach>
    </form>
</body>
```

And below is my controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/atc/edit", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView editATC(@ModelAttribute("message") String message, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException
{
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("action"));
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("atcId"));
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("view_ATCMaster");
    mav.addObject("message", message);
    return mav;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set all JSTL values as input tag(of type hidden) with proper names/ids. Then you can able to access those hidden inputs in your controller by using

`request.getParameterValues("hiddenInputId");`